# Finding duplicate values and number of their repetitions in javascript

Tags: javascript, duplicates

I am trying to create n number of arrays in a new array(multipleArrays). Next step is to find duplicates in that multipleArrays and how many times they repeat. I am using 2 functions. First one is to create the main array with 35 numbers out of 48 numbers. The second function is gathering all those arrays into one array.

```
function createArray35() {
const array35 = [];
i = 0;
do {
    var rng = Math.floor(Math.random() * 48) + 1;
    if (!array35.includes(rng)) {
        array35.push(rng);
        i++;
    }
}
while (i < 35)
return array35
}
createArray35();


function multipleArray(total_number) {
var arrayOfArrays = [];
for (z = 0; z <= total_number; z++) {
    var array35 = createArray35();

    arrayOfArrays.push(niz35)

}
return arrayOfArrays;
}
var total_arrays = 3; // total number of "array35" I want to ceate in 
                  // "multipleArray"
console.log(multipleArray(arrayOfArrays));
```

Expected result should be:

1. Number 1 is repeated (n) times;
2. Number 2 is repeated (n) times;
3. ...
4. ...
5. Number 47 is repeated (n) times
6. Number 48 is repeated (n) times

Thank you all in advance

Comment: `arrayOfArrays.push(niz35)` — what's `niz35`?  The variable in that function is called `arrayOfArrays`. Also you forgot to declare `z` with `let` or `var`.

Comment: Sorry for not stating it right.
arrayOfArrays.push(niz35) ... niz35 is variable array35, I just forgot to translate it.
z is "var z".

Comment: But ... JavaScript doesn't know that. You call `createArray35()` and store the result in `array35`, but then you use a variable that is not declared. That won't work. Post the *real* code that you're having problems with. It wastes people's time if you post code that does not reflect the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code with comments:

```js
// This method of getting X unique numbers from Y set is recommended, because it has a stable execution time
function createArray35() {
  // create a [1 .... 48] array
  var candidates = Array.from({
    length: 48
  }).map((el, index) => index + 1);

  var array35 = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
    // remove 1 random number from candidates
    const positionToRemove = Math.floor(Math.random() * candidates.length);
    const randomNum = candidates.splice(
      positionToRemove,
      1
    )[0];

    array35.push(randomNum);
  }
  return array35
}

function multipleArray(total_number) {
  var arrayOfArrays = Array.from({
    length: total_number
  }).map(el => createArray35());

  return arrayOfArrays;
}

function countDuplicates(arrayOfArrays) {
  // Create an array of length 48 where each element is 0;
  var counters = Array.from({
    length: 48
  }).map(el => 0);

  // Each time a number appear, increase its corresponding counter by 1
  for (var array of arrayOfArrays) {
    for (var number of array) {
      counters[number - 1] = counters[number - 1] + 1;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
    console.log(`Number ${i+1} is repeated ${counters[i]} times;`);
  }
}

var total_arrays = 3;
var arrayOfArrays = multipleArray(total_arrays);

console.log(arrayOfArrays);

countDuplicates(arrayOfArrays);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function createArray35() {
    const array35 = [];
    i = 0;
    do {
        var rng = Math.floor(Math.random() * 48) + 1;
        if (!array35.includes(rng)) {
            array35.push(rng);
            i++;
        }
    }
    while (i < 35)
    return array35;
    }

function CalculateCount(array){
    var result = {};
    for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        var obj = array[i].toString();
       if(result[obj]){
           result[obj] = result[obj]+1;
       }
       else{
        result[obj] = 1;
       }
    }
    return result;
}

function PrintResult(result){
    for(var i in result){
        console.log(`Number ${i} is repeated (${result[i]}) times;`);
    }
}

var resultObject = CalculateCount(createArray35());
PrintResult(resultObject);
```

Comment: Tnx for this, but it is still not working. I wanted to add more than one array into multiple arrays and then to check the number of repetitions on all numbers in all arrays. But tnx for the answer.